# How to avoid unwanted change in IntelliSense behaviour in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

Having recently upgraded from Visual Studio 2013 to Visual Studio 2015, I have noticed a subtle change in the way IntelliSense works, especially when modifying code.

Consider the following simple code fragment:

```
 int length = 1, width = 2, height = 3;
 int area = length * height;
```

Let's say I want to change variable `height` in the second line to `width`. I would put the cursor at the start of the word `height` and type <kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> (or Edit.CompleteWord) to invoke the IntelliSence word completion list.

Under Visual Studio 2013, it would conveniently show a list, already positioned at `width`, allowing me to press  to complete the change.

[Screen shot showing Word Completion under Visual Studio 2013](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWNM6.jpg)

Under Visual Studio 2015, the same actions presents a very different word completion list.

[Screen shot showing Word Completion under Visual Studio 2015](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6B7F5.jpg)

Note that the word that I am looking for (`width`) is in the list, but a long way down. It would appear that I need to first remove the unwanted text (the `height` part of `wiheight`) in order to get the completion list to find part of the list containing the names that start with `wi`.

Similar differences in behaviour occur for other IntelliSense items such as class names and method names.

Is there a way, in Visual Studio 2015, to have IntelliSense work the way it used to in Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: The changes in VS2015 are not exactly subtle.  Roslyn has *heavily* affected the behavior of IntelliSense as well as the compiler.   Nothing anybody can do about this, click the [New Issue button](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues).